# Having containers over other containers

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, containers

I'm encountering a problem with Container views. I want to have a Container (with its embedSegue and childViewController) over another Container, and both being able to catch user interactions.

Two image will illustrate my words :

In my storyboard :
[image: in my storyboard :]

In my simulator :

[image: In my simulator :]

My problem is that only the button over is clickable. I thought apple's Containers were made so if no UIElement catches the touch then it is sent to the subviews, I was obviously wrong.

With this in mind, here's my question :

Is there anyway to achieve that in interface builder **ONLY** ? If not, do I have to implement a custom container ? Or an override of the `hitTest:withEvent:` in my DeviceViewController is mandatory ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're trying to achieve can be achieved in another way, other than having 2 **containers** on top of each other :\

Now, I don't believe there is **any way** of getting the touch events to work on both containers from the storyboards only. I don't think that implementing your own container would change any of the current behaviour, you're gonna end up implementing Apple's containers in a way, coz you don't seem to have the extra functionality on your containers (( although you don't have enough description of your problem )). And exactly like what you said in your question, i think the only way to achieve what you want (( under the current circumstances )) is to implement `hitTest:withEvent:`.

P.S: I would suggest that you give a little bit more details about the problem you're facing, and I might be able to give you an alternative solution other than the way you're going with right now =)

Comment: thx for the answer ! I understand that there's a lot of better ways to  achieve view superposition, I'm really just trying to have "smart" containers, keeping the events when then have a UIElement as the touch target and relaying them when they don't.